# Does the use of 'var' in a method make the execution(concurrently) thread unsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, mutable

I have read in multiple places that in functional programming we should not use variables that can be mutated.

```
def total (list:List[Int]) :Int = {
  var sum =0 
  for(i<- list){
    sum = sum+i
  }
  return sum
}
```

This is a simple method that totals a list. Will this be thread safe. Will the use of var cause problems if many instances of this method are executed simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is thread-safe because `sum` var is local var. In other case (when `sum` shared between threads) your code will be incorrect.

```
var sum: Int = 0
for (_ <- 1 to 10000) {
    new Thread(new Runnable {
        override def run() = sum += 10
    }).start()
}
// wait threads
println(sum)
```

The code above will not print `100000` every time because `+=` operator isn' atomic. Really it has 3 steps.

1. Read `sum` value from variable
2. Increase `sum` value
3. Write increased value to variable

Two parallel threads can evaluate 1'st step at the same time (and read value 550 e.g.). After that every thread will increase value by 10 and write new value (560) to `sum`. As result we will get sum less than `100000` sometimes.

You can use `AtomicInteger` to fix it. `AtomicInteger` has atomic `increment`, `compareAndSet`, `addAndGet` etc. operations.

```
 val sum: AtomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0)
 for (_ <- 1 to 10000) {
    new Thread(new Runnable {
        override def run() = sum.addAndGet(10)
    }).start()
 }
 // wait threads
 println(sum)
```

Code above will print correct result every time due to `addAndGet` atomacity.

Answer (score 3):

Mutable variables, `var`s, become a problem in multithreding if they are *shared* among threads. In the example you give, the problem is not represented by the `var sum`, that is not a shared mutable variable (or state, to be more precise). `sum` is local to your method and cannot be accessed from the outside.

The only problem should be the input of the method, `list:List[Int]`. Is this list Immutable? If you use any implementation of `scala.collection.immutable.List`, everything will go right. The only possible shared state between thread is immutable, than it cannot change during the execution of `total` method.

Remember that every time you use a shared mutable state you have to be sure that the state is accesed in a *mutually exclusive* way. This means to use mechanisms of thread confinement, such as *synchronization*, *atomic variables*, and so on.

In summary, multithreading problems do not come from `var` or `val` use, but from the fact that you can shared *mutable* state between threads.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `sum` is a local variable. Local variables are stored in each thread's own stack, so they are not shared between threads. This means your method would be thread safe.

On the other hand if your variable is not a local one than you need to make sure the access to it is synchronized (if it's mutable and accessed from more than one place).